# How to retrieve JSON data in controller in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a button and added a jquery click event to that as below.

```
$("#saveMe").click(function ()
{

        var car = { name: 'intro to asp.net', price:5200};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Book/saveData",
            data: car,
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("successfully saved in DB");
            }
        });

});
```

I need to access these JSON data in controller action. I need to to get the value for name and price separately.And also i need to assign the name value for name attribute in book model and price value for price attribute in book mode. 
My controller action is like below.

```
public ActionResult saveData()
        {    
            String name =  //assign json data.name.
            double price= //assign json.data.price
            book.name=name // **Is this a correct way to assign values to the mode?**

        }
```

I am a beginner in asp.net and I really can't solve this problem.Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the parameters to your method so its

```
public ActionResult saveData(string name, decimal price)
{
  ...
}
```

or create a model (say `class Book`) with 2 properties (`string name` and `decimal price`) so the model is bound with the values

```
public ActionResult saveData(Book model)
```

Comment: Can you just say, how to retrieve the passed json data?

Comment: What do you mean? In the first example, the parameter `name` will have the value `"intro to asp.net"` and the parameter `price` will have the value `5200`. In the second example, `model.name` and `model.price` will have the values. What else are you expecting?

Comment: Can you guide me to pass the values to the mode. I created a ado.net entity model for the BOOK table. I need to pass the retrieved name and price to the BOOK model.how can i do this?

Comment: Then if you already have a model named `Book` and it has propertes named `Name` and `Price` then use the second example. Otherwise, in the first example, use `var book = new Book(){ name = name, price = price };` But you really need to show your model if you cant understand the code.

Comment: Sorry ,I just forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult saveData(string name, double price) { ...
```

Comment: Can you just say, how to retrieve the passed json data?

Comment: Do you see the parameters of the controller method have the same name with your json object? They will retrieve the data passed from your ajax request.

You can also directly use the model as the parameter, like @Stephen Muecke suggested. Notice that you must name the properties of the model same as JSON object that you sent from the client.